# Airflow DAG changes not reflected in the Airflow web UI and logs are not updated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Context -

I'm facing an issue with Apache Airflow where changes I make to my DAG are not being reflected in the Airflow web UI, and the logs for my DAG are not updating as expected. However DAGs are getting triggered using the REST API. I'm not sure what's causing this problem, and I could use some help troubleshooting it.

Additional Information -

I initially set up airflow in my GCP VM and it was working fine. However when I pushed ( migrated or transferred )  the code inside another folder named ( say ‘etl’ ) I am facing the above mentioned issue.

I tried re-initiating the airflow database - airflow db init. However the changes or the logs are still not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your scheduler's health, since it's his job to update that info for the webserver to consume.

You have two options for doing that:

1.Check the /health endpoint to see his health status and lastest heartbeat. In case your don't know what '/health endpoint' means, it's the url you use to acess Airflow's Webserver + '/health', e.g. 'localhost:8080/health'.

2.Check scheduler's logs and see if you find anything interesting there. In case you are using docker, use 'docker logs SCHEDULER-CONTAINER-ID' for that.

If none of these helps you, please feel free to share more about your airflow project.

Source: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/check-health.html

Answer (score 0):

Are the updated DAGs *never* showing up or just taking a long time? If they never show up, you might need to update the [dags_folder](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dags-folder) config setting. You can also check your DAG parser logs (these can probably be found in the scheduler logs) for any timeouts or errors. If it's just taking a long time, you should check to see if the [dag_dir_list_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-dir-list-interval) configuration setting is long enough.